# FDR estimation from distribution and reference

Tags: statistical-significance, false-discovery-rate

I would like to have FDR/estimated FDR from two distributions with different mean and similar sigma. One of this is a reference distribution of 'real' samples (TP) while the other one is predicted (containing FP + TP).

Of course I could generate a null distribution and then just estimate FDR with that. I was wondering whether having the knowledge what is TP and what is FP will allow to do something as naive as just taking the predicted samples calculate local FDR directly (TP/P) and then filter for whatever threshold.

Comment: The trick that may work under some conditions (good separation between your models and large sample size): you take all the values from FP+TP and take their p-values according to the distribution of TP. 2 * (amount of p-values > 0.5) will give you an expected number of TPs in your FP+TP. In general your task is "estimate amount of FP in FP+TP distribution" - it is the job for mixture model analysis.

Comment: The two mean of the two distributions are very different (p < 10-68). So the conversion to p will be the test of mean difference with permutation test / bootstrap? Also for do you mean gaussian mixture model with 2 components?

Comment: No no, p value is not from the test, p value is from the distribution of true positives. Basically, how big is the proportion of true positives bigger than the observed value. And yes, gaussian mixture will be fine, parameters for one model you can estimate from your tp distribution.

Comment: Okok, so just quantile right? Also, which assumptions are we making? normality of both distribution? Sorry I am not the best statistician in the world

Comment: yeap. if the distributions intersect largely - go from 50% quantile to like 10% or 20% top quantile from TP distributions, but then you will need to multiply by 10 or 5 (since p-value is uniformly distributed for the large enough sample). Actually there is no assumptions. If you do mixture analysis - you assume some family of distributions, but here I'd say no.

Comment: Okok, I am just writing the code for it, so to sum up. convert to p via quantile then learn the gmm from the TP(using mu and sigma from the TP) and calculate likelihood probabilities for each sample from TP+FP distribution. Then FDR how is controlled?

Comment: No-no, there are 2 approaches: either with p-values or with Gausian Mixture. With both approaches you do not control FDR - you estimate FDR (the question was about estimation). You may reduce the number of FP by cutting the observations that do not look like TP - but this is another story =)

Comment: Gotcha, my bad. so lemme recap. 1) convert to p-value do multiple testing correction (i guess) and then just control individual level fdr. 2) just chunk through a gmm and figure out there the threshold for separation of the two distributions

Comment: I can write an answer I think

Answer (score 0):

To estimate FDR you need to estimate the number of True Positives in your mixture.[image] (I took this picture from [here](https://angusturner.github.io/generative_models/2017/11/03/pytorch-gaussian-mixture-model.html)).

Here the example is mixture of normals, but in theory the approach should work for any distribution (reasonable ones with reasonable sample sizes and intersections). So, what do you have:

1) green density of TP+FP
2) orange density of TPs

The key observation: how many FPs are on the right from the top-10% quantile of orange distribution (the exact value on x-axis may be around 6 in the particular picture)? Almost 0. And you know that 10% of TPs are on the right of this threshold.

Basically, you find how many of your values that form the green density are on the right of this threshold. Then you multiply this number by 10 (since we know that 10% of TPs are on the right). This is how you estimate the number of TPs in the mixture of TPs and FPs.

Of course, these values (10% or 5% or 50%) should be adapted depending on how big is the intersection between the components. If there is only 1% difference - well, then you'll need a lot of samples and 1% threshold.